# Bootstrap tabs not displaying correctly when window too small

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a nav menu using the tabs from bootstrap. It's all good, but when the window is at such width that the tabs (justified) are not yet stacked, it's displaying weirdly (because some tabs are now taking two lines rather than one line), as you can see:

Good:

[image: screencap good]

Bad:

[image: screencap bad]

And here's the HTML:

```
<ul id="onglets" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#mod" data-toggle="tab"> addition (polaire) </a></li>
    <li><a href="#com" data-toggle="tab"> addition (composantes) </a></li>
    <li><a href="#con" data-toggle="tab"> conversion d'angles </a></li>
    <li><a href="#mul" data-toggle="tab"> produit </a></li>
    <li><a href="#uni" data-toggle="tab">vecteur unitaire </a></li>
</ul>
```

I think I've found the CSS related to nav-justified in my bootstrap.min.css:

```
.nav-tabs.nav-justified{width:100%;border-bottom:0}.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li{float:none}.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a{text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px}.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.dropdown .dropdown-menu{top:auto;left:auto}@media (min-width:768px){.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li{display:table-cell;width:1%}.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a{margin-bottom:0}}.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a{margin-right:0;border-radius:4px}.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a,.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:hover,.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:focus{border:1px solid #ddd}@media (min-width:768px){.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a{border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:4px 4px 0 0}.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a,.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:hover,.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:focus{border-bottom-color:#fff}}
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Edit: So, by playing with the bootstrap.min.css file, I was able to change the @media query to change the tabs to be stacked to 992px rather than 768px (as it would start to be corrupted at 991px). It works, but if someone has a better solution, I am open!

Comment: Is this with Bootstrap v3.2.0? Does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: At least 3, I don't remember exactly which one though. And yes, chrome and firefox

Comment: Please could you post the CSS as well.

Comment: There's no css, that's how bootstrap displays the HTML (if you ignore the buttons under the nav, it has nothing to do with it)

Comment: i think because of .nav-justified class try removing it

Comment: @Jonathan But what CSS is Bootstrap using to style the tabs?

Comment: I've tried without nav-justified, and it's not good aesthetically, and the tabs don't stack when the window gets to a certain width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `white-space:nowrap;` you can make the tabs always display in a single line, this may be a solution for you:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    #onglets>li>a {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

[**Demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/6gL18fbu/3/)